# Azure AD App permissions to other application using WebAccountProvider in UWP

Tags: oauth-2.0, uwp, azure-active-directory

I need help regarding the accessing the AAD resource from universal windows app.

1. I have a ASP.NET MVC project and deployed to Azure AAD.
2. I have a Native Azure APP and  through permissions to other applications I have given access to my ASP.NET MVC project (#1).
3. Using WebAccountProvider model in UWP I have got the access token for client id of #2.
4. When I query for Office 365/SharePoint Online I see the data coming fine.
5. But, if I query for content of #1 web site then response is showing redirect to login.microsoftonline.com.

The preliminary check validated are:

1. My application is using OWIN startup.
2. It has ClientID, Audience defined in my web.config.
3. The manifest is looking fine with Type=User and value=user_impresonation.

Anyone help in understanding what else is missing from configuration?

Note: Very first time users got the Consent and it is showing all list correctly.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I have resolved the issue! The issue was for my web site resource I should end the url with the "/" at the end. This looks so odd, but it's true.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue! The issue was while getting token for a different resource (my custom mvc web site) I should end the url of the resource with the "/" at the end. This looks so odd, but it's true.